# backbone Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, autocomplete

I'm working of this code,

```
<script>
  autocompleteRemote = new Backbone.AutocompleteList({
    url: function() { return 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.search&api_key=cef6d600c717ecadfbe965380c9bac8b&format=json&' + $.param({ artist: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]').val() }); },
    filter: null,
    el: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]'),
    template: _.template('<p><%= name.replace(new RegExp("(" + $("form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]").val() + ")", "i") ,"<b>$1</b>") %></p>'),
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 3,
    value: function(model) { return model.get('name') },
  }).resultsView.collection.parse = function(resp) {
    return resp.results.artistmatches.artist;
  };
</script>
```

But I'm trying to connect it to the tmdb api like this,

```
autocompleteRemote = new Backbone.AutocompleteList({
  url: function() {
    return 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=' + api + '&' + $.param({query: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]').val()})
  },

  filter: null,

  el: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]'),
  template: _.template(
    '<p><%= name.replace(new RegExp("(" + $("form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]").val() + ")", "i") ,"<b>$1</b>") %></p>'
  ),
  delay: 500,
  minLength: 3,
  value: function(model) { return model.get('name') }
  ,

  })

  .resultsView.collection.parse = function(resp) {
    return resp.results.moviematches.query;
  };

  var api = 'a8f7039633f206xx42cd8a28d7cadad4'
```

As you can see I changed a few things like the url and put the api key in a var to clean up the code a bit. I also changed the word `artist` to `query` so it would give me back the right url. But I'm getting a error in the console log and I'm drawing a blanc.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
Backbone.AutocompleteList.resultsView.collection.parse 
.extend.set
options.success
fire
self.fireWith
done
callback
```

The source material can be found here -> http://aghull.github.io/coding/2013/03/09/Backbone-autocomplete-lists/ Autocomplete using remote Collection

Comment: The error suggests that resp.results.moviematches isn't defined - have you inspected that response to verify this yourself?

Comment: Hm, it looks like `return resp.results.artistmatches.artist;` has to do with the audioscrobbler API. So `moviematches` isn't anything. Do you perhaps have a suggestion on what I have to call it to show movies from tmdb?

Comment: Do a console.dir(resp.results) so you can inspect that response and see where it contains the properties you're interested in. I don't know anything about the api, so I don't have a specific answer for you.

Comment: I use google chrome debugger and set breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/reference/search/searchlist/get?console=1) is a nice resource which will help to find out response body. As I can see from test response generated there, there is no `moviematches` property. You need `resp.results` which is just a collection (array) of objects (movies I guess).

So you need to change your code to:

```
var api = 'a8f7039633f206xx42cd8a28d7cadad4';

autocompleteRemote = new Backbone.AutocompleteList({
  url: function() {
    return 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=' + api + '&' + $.param({query: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]').val()})
  },

  filter: null,

  el: $('form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]'),
  template: _.template(
    '<p><%= name.replace(new RegExp("(" + $("form#autocomplete-remote input[name=search]").val() + ")", "i") ,"<b>$1</b>") %></p>'
  ),
  delay: 500,
  minLength: 3,
  value: function(model) { return model.get('name') }
  ,

  }).resultsView.collection.parse = function(resp) {
    return resp.results;
  };
```

I tried to make a comment but it became an answer :)

**Edit:**

Use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvahans/d9L6Lbwn/3/) for tests. Place correct API_KEY and try again. I have tried with your existing api_key, but it's invalid.

Comment: Hm! When I eddit my code I don't get any errors and when I look in my network overview in Chrome I can see the requests I make. But it doesn't show the results in an autocomplete/suggestion sort of way. Do you have any tips on that? Anyway great thanks so far.

Comment: I played around a bit and found out that the script was working (it showed results in network overview) but not in my search. I checked the actual DOM and saw that I was getting a list of empty P elements. After changing `name` in the template and the value to `original_title` (which is the name of the movie in the JSON) it actually works :).